# Убрать лишние символы в адресе страниц htacces

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как убрать в конце расширение типа ".php" ясно. 
У меня есть ссылки вида: *.org/?file=main
Гугл такое не ест. 
Помогите написать правило в htacces для отображение вида:
*.org/main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?file=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?file=$1
```